# "/proc/self" - Dynamically changing a soft link

Tags: kernel, directory, process, symbolic-link

I was wandering on the Linux filesystem, which looks like a good way of understanding how it works. In UNIX "everything is a file", so I was looking at `/dev/stdin` and noticed it is a soft link to `/proc/self/fd/0`. So I decided to go take a look at the `/proc` folder, finding that `/proc/self` is actually a soft link to `/proc/{PID}`. To be more precise, the PID is the one of the `ls -l /proc/self` command I issue to check its value.

My theory is that the soft link is changed everytime a program tries to read it, to point to the right PID process folder. Is this done by the kernel on every request it gets to read the `/proc` folder? I don't think you need to actually read the file to get the output of `ls` or we wouldn't be able to see files with 700 permission, so does the soft link change happens when the `/proc` folder is accessed?

Going even further: Is this kind of control restricted for the kernel itself or can some applications make use of that? (Maybe checking when a folder is being accessed to dynamically change its contents/links according to "who" is doing it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/proc` is a mount point for `procfs` (kind of `tmpfs`, lives in memory), which is an interface to the kernel's internal data structure. Whatever you see in `/proc` is directly populated by Linux and also maintained by the kernel itself.

`/proc/self` is a symlink to the `/proc/<PID>` directory, where `<PID>` is the Process ID of the process accessing `/proc` at that very instant. So while in `bash` if you do `cd /proc/self`, you will be `cd`-id into the `/proc/<PID>/`, where `<PID>` is the PID for that instance of `bash`, while if some other process, let's say for `cat`:

```
$ cat /proc/self/comm
cat
```

You should absolutely not change anything in `/proc` except if kernel provides some interface to change the values. For example, kernel provides the interface `/proc/sys/` to change kernel parameters at runtime, although mostly you should use `sysctl` to change values under `/proc/sys/` rather than directly editing any file. Mishandling of Kernel's internal data structure would result in an unusable system or even system crash.

Comment: Is the reason the `cd /proc/self`redirects to the bash `/proc/<BASH_PID>` and `ls -l /proc/self` shows the `/proc/<LS_PID>` the fact `cd` is a shell built-in and `ls` is a binary application?

Comment: @IanC spot on..